# Unlock LUKS non-root filesystem partition on boot

Tags: ssh, boot, systemd, luks, initramfs

I have a system with an unencrypted `/` partition on Ubuntu 16.04, but with a LUKS encrypted ZFS zpool on 3 partitions. In order for the system to boot properly I want for the LUKS encrypted volumes to be unlocked before ZFS and other services (like database, web, email etc.) start, and this needs to be able to done remotely, through SSH.

With the 3 partitions added to the `/etc/crypttab`, the system boots and just after the `initramfs` stage will wait for unlock (and prompt for passwords). However, the usual way of accomplishing LUKS unlock at boot remotely is done through `dropbear` in `initramfs`, however because the 3 partitions are not in `fstab` the system will 'fall through' `initramfs` so to speak and continue to `systemd`. This is undesirable in this case as `systemd` prioritizes `crypttab` over the `OpenSSH` or `dropbear` meaning remote unlocking is disabled.

A dirty hack that works is simply adding a `sleep 300` in initramfs, giving you time to login through `dropbear` and unlock, however this too is undesirable. I see foresee two options to fix this, but am not sure which would be best and I do not know how to implement either:

- Changhing `systemd` boot order, to make sure something like `networking` and `OpenSSH` are up before `crypttab`, enabling remote or local unlocking.
- Having `initramfs` wait for non-trivial partitions to be unlocked before proceeding to `systemd`.

Comment: Just add/modify unit files so that the decryption happens before the rest.

Answer (score 1):

1. unlock luks in ubuntu
2. add ",initramfs" at the end to /etc/crypttab

```
root@a:~# cat /etc/crypttab
vda6_crypt UUID=9f420e32-0821-4cc8-a87e-59db96a12df0 none luks,discard 
vdb_crypt  UUID=8632fd8d-46ca-4c82-931c-6f6e04066465 none luks,discard,initramfs
```

3. update-initramfs -u
4. check /cryptroot/crypttab file

```
root@a:~# unmkinitramfs /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-50-generic /tmp/initramfs
root@a:~# cat /tmp/initramfs/main/cryptroot/crypttab

vda6_crypt UUID=9f420e32-0821-4cc8-a87e-59db96a12df0 none luks,discard
vdb_crypt UUID=8632fd8d-46ca-4c82-931c-6f6e04066465 none luks,discard,initramfs
```

Answer (score 0):

I am currently setting up such a system, but in debian stretch. And I am doing my experimentation in a VM before I actually set up the physical computer itself. I have a very similar setup working in the VM.

2 disks in zpool mirror for /, but not /boot. /boot is on md0. zpool is on top of LUKS. Using EFI.

```
root@zstaging:~# cat /proc/1/comm
systemd

root@zstaging:~# lsblk
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0   20G  0 disk
+-sda1            8:1    0  256M  0 part
¦ +-md0           9:0    0  256M  0 raid1 /boot
+-sda2            8:2    0  256M  0 part  /boot/efi
+-sda3            8:3    0 19.5G  0 part
¦ +-disk0_crypt 253:0    0 19.5G  0 crypt
+-sda9            8:9    0    9M  0 part
sdb               8:16   0   20G  0 disk
+-sdb1            8:17   0  256M  0 part
¦ +-md0           9:0    0  256M  0 raid1 /boot
+-sdb2            8:18   0  256M  0 part
+-sdb3            8:19   0 19.5G  0 part
¦ +-disk1_crypt 253:1    0 19.5G  0 crypt
+-sdb9            8:25   0    9M  0 part
sdc               8:32   0   20G  0 disk
sr0              11:0    1  1.8G  0 rom

root@zstaging:~# zpool status
  pool: rpool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: none requested
config:

        NAME             STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        rpool            ONLINE       0     0     0
          mirror-0       ONLINE       0     0     0
            disk0_crypt  ONLINE       0     0     0
            disk1_crypt  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

Relevant files and setup:

```
root@zstaging:~# cat /etc/fstab
UUID=648bfa4b-1b5f-480a-bb26-b3abffb4a6de /boot auto defaults 0 0
PARTUUID=1673f966-173b-4128-84d5-4e8d5810efef /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1

root@zstaging:~# cat /etc/crypttab
disk0_crypt UUID=26194846-ba49-4e53-ab0b-857b0dad2021 none luks
disk1_crypt UUID=ef44b66a-8706-4be2-bd12-a30d40de9669 none luks

root@zstaging:~# cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/cryptroot
target=disk0_crypt,source=UUID=26194846-ba49-4e53-ab0b-857b0dad2021,key=none,rootdev
target=disk1_crypt,source=UUID=ef44b66a-8706-4be2-bd12-a30d40de9669,key=none,rootdev

set CRYPTSETUP=y in /etc/cryptsetup-initramfs/conf-hook

# vi /etc/default/grub
replace GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="" with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="boot=zfs"
Remove quiet from: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT
Uncomment: GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# update-initramfs -u -k all
# update-grub
# grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=debian --recheck --no-floppy
```

Everything works great. Get prompt for unlocking the two disks one at a time, and off we go. It is NOT necessary to list any zfs stuff in /etc/fstab. Yes, initramfs etc. WILL complain about /etc/fstab, but it all works fine, so far

I can even remote unlock it

```
# apt-get install dropbear-initramfs busybox
# vi /etc/dropbear-initramfs/authorized_keys
Paste my SSH pubkey

# chmod 400 /etc/dropbear-initramfs/authorized_keys
# update-initramfs -u

in another machine that has my SSH keys, add a custom section in ~/.ssh/config:
  Host zstaging_unlock
  HostName <ip_of_zstaging>
  User root
  HostKeyAlias zstaging_unlock

to remote unlock zstaging, from remote machine:
$ ssh zstaging_unlock
and follow prompts
```

HTH